# QTimer isActive returns true, but remainingTime returns -1

Tags: c++, qt, qtimer

A timer is defined and started in the beginning:

```
QTimer *teleTimer;
teleTimer = new QTimer();
QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction1())); 
teleTimer->start(200);
```

Then it is stopped somewhere and another function `somefunction2()` is called. After that function finished, the timer is started again:

```
if (teleTimer->isActive())
{
    qDebug() << teleTimer->remainingTime();
    teleTimer->stop();
    delete teleTimer;
}
teleTimer = new QTimer();
QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction3())); 
teleTimer->start(200);
```

However, `teleTimer->isActive()` returns `true`, while `teleTimer->remainingTime()` returns `-1`, then the application is crashed:

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: QThread
0   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ed4be3b QObject::killTimer(int) + 27
1   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ed5a9b9 QTimer::stop() + 25
2   com.yourcompany.QTGCS           0x000000010dffa609 TelemetrySerialWorker::setTelemetryMode(int) + 745 (telemetryserialworker.cpp:114)
```

So how to fix this? Thanks.

Update: This problem is solved. Thanks for all the replies. I will try to post a question in a good format next time. Thanks.

Comment: change `delete teleTimer()` to `delete teleTimer->deleteLater();`

Comment: @eyllanesc Do you mean change to `teleTimer->deleteLater();` ? I tried it, but still crashes. I think the problem comes from `teleTimer->stop()` rather than `delete`.

Comment: @eyllanesc You might be right... Let me do more tests.

Comment: Could be a race condition since multiple threads are involved according to the stack trace. Can you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that reproduces the crash?

Comment: Just out of interest, *why* are you deleting the timer? It seems that you should just be able to stop it and start it without deleting. You don't even need to re-connect in that case.

Comment: @paxdiablo That is because in my code, I actually connected to different slots. I didn't show this in the sample above.

Comment: @paxdiablo It is actually `somefunction1()`, `somefunction2()`, `somefunction3()`, ... . I didn't type in. I use the timer with different intervals. But your comment makes sense. It is not necessary. Great advice.

Comment: Ah, that makes more sense now. However, you *still* don't need to delete and recreate, you *could* simply disconnect and connect to the new slot. The reason I mention this is because it's sometimes the case that a timer callback is "in-flight" during deletion that causes these issues. Disc/conn won't result in the rug being pulled out from under in-flight callbacks. Still, you've solved it so no need to continue, I just thought I'd mention my reasoning.

Comment: @paxdiablo Yeah, you are right. It totally makes sense. Great advice.

Comment: This is a very poor question: please create a self-contained, single file example that shows how you use those multiple functions. You're most likely complicating things quite a bit. Is this question in relation to the QtGCS project? If so -- please show exactly what in the code you're trying to fix.

Comment: @KubaOber Thanks for your comment. I will try to do as you suggested next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, if you're invoking functions in a sequence, it's simplest to keep the sequence in a table, and use single-shot timers. Recreating timers or connections is expensive.

```
#include <QtCore>
#include <functional>
#include <initializer_list>

class Sequencer : public QObject {
public:
  using base_class = QObject;
  struct Element {
    int delay = 0;
    std::function<void()> functor;
  };
  explicit Sequencer(QObject *parent = {}) : QObject(parent) {}
  // takes care of initializer list and other compatible initializers
  Sequencer(QVector<Element> init, QObject *parent = {}) : 
    QObject(parent), m_sequence(std::move(init)) {}
  void start(int index = 0) {
    m_it = m_sequence.begin() + index;
    m_timer.start(m_it->delay, this);
  }
  int stop() {
    m_timer.stop();
    return m_it - m_sequence.begin();
  }
protected:
  void timerEvent(QTimerEvent *event) override {
    if (m_timer.timerId() != event->timerId())
      return base_class::timerEvent(event);
    m_it->functor();
    m_it++;
    if (m_it != m_sequence.end())
      m_timer.start(m_it->delay, this);
    else
      m_timer.stop();
  }
private:
  QVector<Element> m_sequence;
  QVector<Element>::const_iterator m_it = m_sequence.begin();     
  QBasicTimer m_timer;
};
```

You'd use it like this, for example:

```
class MyClass { // can be QObject, but doesn't have to be
  Sequence m_seq{
    {200, [=]{ function1(); }},   // after 200ms delay
    {0,   [=]{ function2(); }},   // after no delay
    {500, [=]{ function3(); }},   // after 500ms delay
    {0,   [=]{ loop(); }}};       // and right away loop the sequence
  void function1();
  void function2();
  void function3();
  void loop() { m_seq.start(); }
public:
  MyClass() {
    m_seq.start();
  }
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have never used the method you mention before. Looks interesting to me, I will try. All the functions are called more than once, for example, initially `somefunction1()` is called every 200ms, then if there is no interaction from GUI, it will call this function every 200 ms infinitely. Then if some button is clicked, it will move on to `somefunction2()` or others.

Answer (score 0):

With the hint given by @eyllanesc, my problem is finally solved.

At the very beginning, I used `delete teleTimer` then my program started to crash. At that time I thought the reason was the timer didn't really stop by the time this function called again. Then I changed my code to run another single shot timer so that it really has a timer to stop.

The very beginning: (crashed)

```
void timerSwitch()
{
    if (teleTimer->isActive())
    {
        qDebug() << teleTimer->remainingTime();
        teleTimer->stop();
        delete teleTimer;
    }
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction())); 
        teleTimer->start(200);
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        somefunction2();
    }

}
```

First change: (crashed)

```
void timerSwitch()
{
    if (teleTimer->isActive())
    {
        qDebug() << teleTimer->remainingTime();
        teleTimer->stop();
        delete teleTimer;
    }
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction())); 
        teleTimer->start(200);
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        teleTimer.singleshot(..., ..., SLOT(somefunction2()));
    }

}
```

Then with the hint given by @eyllanesc, I changed my code to:

```
void timerSwitch()
{
    if (teleTimer->isActive())
    {
        qDebug() << teleTimer->remainingTime();
        teleTimer->stop();
        teleTimer->deleteLater();
    }
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction())); 
        teleTimer->start(200);
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        teleTimer.singleshot(..., ..., SLOT(somefunction2()));
    }

}
```

My program still crashed.

Then I changed my code to:

```
void timerSwitch()
{
    if (teleTimer->isActive())
    {
        qDebug() << teleTimer->remainingTime();
        teleTimer->stop();
        teleTimer->deleteLater();
    }
    if (mode == 1)
    {
        teleTimer = new QTimer();
        QObject::connect(teleTimer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(somefunction())); 
        teleTimer->start(200);
    }
    else if (mode == 2)
    {
        somefunction2();
    }

}
```

This time my program works fine. I tested more than 20 times, all working correctly and didn't crash.

In the process, all the reasons given by my computer are similar to this:

```
Thread 2 Crashed:: QThread
0   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ed4be3b QObject::killTimer(int) + 27
1   org.qt-project.QtCore           0x000000010ed5a9b9 QTimer::stop() + 25
2   com.yourcompany.QTGCS           0x000000010dffa609 TelemetrySerialWorker::setTelemetryMode(int) + 745 (telemetryserialworker.cpp:114)
```

I thought the error came out from `stop()`, since `isActive()` returns `true`, but `remainingTime()` returns `-1`. My understanding was when `isActive()` was called, the timer was indeed not stopped somehow, but when `remainingTime()` was called, the timer was stopped. Then I felt this should not be so stupid. I still have my doubt, but my problem is solved. I will update more details when I get time. Thanks all the fellows replied me.